# Can not bind data to a model attribute list in jsp

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, modelattribute

I am learning spring mvc and jsp. I have a form in my jsp file. What I want is to change the values of parsing Boolean list to the jsp file using model attributes. Let me clarify more, I am parsing a list to jsp file in my controller. List contains Boolean values. First, i need to create row for each item in the list with a checkbox. If the Boolean value is true checkbox need to be checked. I have done this part. But the problem is, when a I click some of the checked boxes. The corresponding value of the need to be change. But after clicking the submit button null list is parsed the controller. I have no idea on this. I have attached the code too.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@EnableAsync
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myMenu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String generateForm(ModelMap model) {
        ObjectDTO menu = new ObjectDTO();
        BaseDataDTO baseDataDTO = new BaseDataDTO();
        baseDataDTO = 
        myService.getRestrictedMenuBaseData();
        List<LitsDTO> listDTOs = myService.getList();
        model.addAttribute("list", listDTOs);
        model.addAttribute("menu", menu);
        return "myMenu";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myMenu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String  populateForm(ModelMap model,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("menu") RestrictedObjectDTO menu,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

        //here i want to print list valus
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Form</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  function setList(){
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listItem">
        if(document.getElementById(listItem.id).checked){
            <c:set target="${listItem}"
                   property = "isdisable"
                   value = "true"  />
        }else{
            <c:set target="${listItem}"
                   property = "isdisable"
                   value = "false"  />
        }
        row = row + 1;
    </c:forEach>        
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="myMenu.do" method='POST' modelAttribute="menu">
        <table> 
            <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listItem">
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="label_names req">${listItem.name}</span>
                        <c:if test="${listItem.disable}">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="${listItem.id}" checked>
                        </c:if> 
                        <c:if test="${!listItem.disable}">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="${listItem.id}">
                        </c:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input class="input_buttons" name="action"
                    style="float: left; margin-left: 281px;" type="submit" value="save" onClick="setList()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </form:form>    
</body>
```

Any help would be nice

Thank you very much...

Comment: Why you combined js with jsp code in `<script>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Reason you are getting empty list on your controller when you submit the form is you have not used spring form controls in your jsp page so spring will not be able to map jsp form values with attributes of your model which you are passing to your controller.

To know how to map spring model attribute with jsp page element you need to look into spring form attibutes.

Take a look to the example given on below link,
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial